# Java, how to check the existence of file

Tags: java, file

I have this small code

```
    File source;
    if ( !source.exists() ) {
        source = new File("instances/student"+student.getStudentID()+".data");
    }
```

The problem is, source is not initialized. Since the whole point is to check if it exists, how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `File` object.

```
File source = new File(...);
```

What constructor you use depends on how you want to locate a file. A simple path String could be enough.

EDIT: just realized the source of your confusion may be that you think creating the `File` object will try to locate the file or create it on the file system. That's not the case. Just calling `new File(...)` won't check its existence or try to create it. A File object is simply an abstraction for a path in your file system. It could be a directory as well.

Comment: Wait, you mean if I do new File(...) it won't overwrite the existing file?

Comment: @vedran Exactly. It won't do anything to the file system. It's just a Java object. Only when you start calling methods like `exists()`, `delete()` or `renameTo` will there be access to the actual file. When you want to alter the contents, you'll need something like a `FileWriter`. To create a non-existing file, you'd call `createNewFile()` on a `File` object. Check the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for accurate info.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
File f = new File(somepathhere);
if ( !f.exists() ) {
    f = new File("instances/student"+student.getStudentID()+".data");
}
```

Or you can check if f.isFile()

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding. Creating a File doesn't create a file on the file system. A File object only really represents a filename. If you want to see whether a file exists, create a File of the appropriate name and check `exists()`.

But then if you want to overwrite or append to a file you don't even need all that. Just create a `new FileOutputStream(...)`, with the `append` parameter set to `true` if you want to append. No need to check beforehand, in fact it is more than a waste of time.